# What will be in 'radiotelephony privileges' part of EASA PPL without practical RT examination?

Tags: radio-communications, easa-regulations, ppl, radio, easa

My question is addressed to pilots who recently obtained PPL in Europe (preferably in Czech Republic, but not so important).

As I understand, EASA itself does not require separate radiotelephony license (FRTOL, RT etc.), but some EU states does.

Does anybody have any recent experience in obtaining EASA PPL in Europe (especially if it is not your domestic country)? What do you have in the 'radiotelephony privileges' part of your license? Have you had to pass a separate practical RT exam?

NOTE: I do not consider UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I got my own license (Czech Republic CAA), and I have "English VFR only" in my "Radiotelephone privileges" section. It is not English proficiency mark (just because I have "ICAO English level 4 valid till..." in "Remarks" section). As I understand, some countries still require separate RT license, but my question was about privileges stated in PPL.

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean "radiotelephony privileges"? The PPL itself doesn't allow you to use radio at all (legally - you shouldn't be even listening to the traffic).

You have to get a separate "Flight Radiotelephony Operator's Licence" issued by any member state (usually issued by the telecommunication regulator).

For each state - you should contact any aviation school / club and they should help you at least pointing out the direction (or giving out some training). This way I got my radio license (aviation RT operator) even in non-domestic country.

Comment: EASA PPL itself contains "Radiotelephony privileges" section (as I know, XII), and something should be specified there (for example, "English, VFR only"). If it is, for the most states it is enough without separate RTOL.

Comment: I believe this is older one, but lets check https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/PPL%28A%29_Lizenz.jpg   (I am learning, but I had to do the RT exam separately)

Comment: I see what the "English" is. It is often used in countries where English is not used very heavily (CZ, SK, HU, ..). In their PPL it's mandatory to have ICAO English level 4 to fly abroad. Though I believe they still need a licence of the "limited radio operator for aviation service". It is not so difficult exam

Comment: Thank you for your try, but I asked just about license, not about RT exam or requirements. Generally if you have "RT privileges" in the license, almost all members does not require separate license (but a few still does), and my question was not about "how to obtain RTOL" or "who requires RTOL". I asked about "RT privileges" section of freshly-issued EASA PPL and whether the holder obliged to pass RT practical exam.

Comment: As I understand, you attached JAR (old) license sample: I suppose that "RT privileges" exists in EASA version, but I also do not know exactly

Comment: Please do not assume. The reason is that there are different licences from different regulators. I really had to do the RT exam separately. I believe the answer for your different post is wrong.

Comment: I kindly ask you to return here and add the info after getting your EASA PPL (and issued state, if possible). I suppose that you are not training in UK, and also you are going to obtain EASA one (not national). Will highly appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58298/discussion-between-gabriel-vince-and-avtomaton).